# Re-Use Address Selection

Tags: addresses

I am interested in finding any research or good examples of offering users to 'Re-Use' a previously entered address when compiling their personal details.

I am working on a new web application which operates a quoting service for property based products, as such when entering initial details to formulate a quote the user must enter the address (or addresses) of the property(ies) in question.

When the user comes to place an order we ask for contact information, including their correspondence address. This correspondence address may or may not have previously been entered. Our existing system offers something similar to below:

[image]

I have been advised by the business that they do not like this solution as believe it to be confusing for user.

I have found similar examples with Deliver & Billing Addresses in eCommerce sites but often the user is entering those details on a single form, as my system will be asking a two separate points in the user journey i am struggling to find a solution that will fit.

Comment: Why do they believe it is confusing?

Answer (score 2):

You're going about it the right way.  Don't make the user enter the address multiple times, if you can avoid it.  You could certainly look at Amazon.com as a pattern.  They allow you to enter an address, if needed, but the default is to use one of the addresses you have already entered.  If you only have one address, provide that.  If you have multiple addresses, provide a dropdown so they can choose one.

You might try changing your text to:

"Use existing address"

or

"Enter new address"

I work with addresses all day, every day.